# How to accurately control time with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm working on a program that transforms a video file by adding an overlay on top of each frame. Think of a GoPro footage onto which we add technical information, like gauges etc. This overlay is generated by some HTML/CSS with animations.

My logic is to launch a headless browser and for each video frame, step the simulation by 1/60 s (for a 60 Hz video), take a screenshot, alpha-blend it on top of the frame, and output a new video frame. While doing so, the webpage is updated.

So, to test that, I used Puppeteer to launch a headless browser with the HTML/CSS below:

```js
function set_value(value) {
    document.querySelector("#animate").innerText = value;
}
set_value(0);
```

```css
#animate {
    animation: 1s linear a forwards;
}

@keyframes a {
    from { width: 0px; }
    to { width: 1000px; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="animate" style="width:0px;height:50px;background:blue;"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;height:4px;width:100px;background:#555;"></div><div style="display:inline-block;height:4px;width:100px;background:#bbb;"></div><div style="display:inline-block;height:4px;width:100px;background:#555;"></div><div style="display:inline-block;height:4px;width:100px;background:#bbb;"></div><div style="display:inline-block;height:4px;width:100px;background:#555;"></div><div style="display:inline-block;height:4px;width:100px;background:#bbb;"></div><div style="display:inline-block;height:4px;width:100px;background:#555;"></div><div style="display:inline-block;height:4px;width:100px;background:#bbb;"></div><div style="display:inline-block;height:4px;width:100px;background:#555;"></div><div style="display:inline-block;height:4px;width:100px;background:#bbb;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows a 1 second animation, each bar representing 100 ms. Here is the code I used to generate screenshots:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: 'new' });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('file:///test.html');
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1020, height: 80 });
    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    await client.send('Emulation.setVirtualTimePolicy', { policy: 'pause' });

    await page.screenshot({ path: `foo0.png`, omitBackground: true });

    for (let i = 1; i < 15; ++i) {
        await page.evaluate(`set_value(${i});`);
        await client.send('Emulation.setVirtualTimePolicy', { policy: 'advance', budget: 10 });
        await page.screenshot({ path: `foo${i}.png`, omitBackground: true });
    }

    await browser.close();
})();
```

It is meant to take a screenshot every 10 ms. But when I take a look at the screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

It appears the browser clearly overstepped the simulation. It also appears that the stride between each step is not consistent.

By adding a delay in the program, I noticed that the simulation continues in real-time and is not paused after stepping.

**How to make sure the rendering only advance by some time delta?**